# div to redirect via code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Hey guys I cant seem to get this to work:

```
div.Attributes.Add("UserFriendsWall.aspx?FriendID=" + Server.UrlEncode(id));
```

Also tryed this:

```
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "UserFriendsWall.aspx?FriendID=" + Server.UrlEncode(id));
```

Is there anyway to redirect while storing id?

maybe

```
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "redirect(" + id + ");");
```

this is only a means if there is no other way with c#

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(id) {
        redirct function via javascript maybe, dont know how tho?('DivClicked', id);

    }


</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think that code should do?

Comment: well i need to "upon" clicking a div redirect me and encode the id for me maybe some javascript might be able to do this not sure, as for that code it was my attempt at doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
div.onclick = function () {
  location = "UserFriendsWall.aspx?FriendID=" + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
};
```

Or if `id` is a variable in local scope, drop the `this.` from the front.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll fix your problem, but you need to tell javascript that it should redirect, i.e.: `window.location.href="UserFriendsWall..."` . At the moment you're just passing a string, which doesn't do anything.